# How to use two joins in jpa in topredacte method

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa

I am using a jpa with spring boot and I'm newbie with this. I have override 
Predicate `toPredicate()` of Specification. below is my code:-

```
 public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ExportOrderInfo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

    if(beginningOfQuarter != null && endOfQuarter != null){
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        root.fetch("orderDetail", JoinType.LEFT);
        root.fetch("orderDownload", JoinType.INNER);
        return builder.and(builder.equal(root.<String>get(randomColumnName), valueToSearchFor) , builder.isNotNull(root.get("optyId")));
    }else{
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        root.fetch("orderDetail", JoinType.LEFT);
        root.fetch("orderDownload", JoinType.LEFT);
        return builder.and(builder.equal(root.<String>get(randomColumnName), valueToSearchFor));
    }
}
```

When I use two root. Fetch its override the previous one. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Are you sure that was it overridden? Maybe it happened because of the INNER join. Also, pls include the class file of the entity you want to get.

Comment: @Selindek yes the query showing only inner join. although i have change root.fetch to root.join and its works but i got org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: More than one row with the given identifier was found error

Comment: pls add the entity sources to the question.

Comment: i have uploaded another question on the same issue. please check following link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158314/its-works-but-i-got-org-springframework-orm-jpa-jpasystemexception-more-than-on

Comment: @ Selindek-  when i use root.join, from select it removes all the columns of  the right hand side tables.